# How to read multiple page invoice pdf using the google cloud vision

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to read the invoice pdf and can read the pdf but only the first page I want to read or convert into string but I cannot do it. here is my code which I have implemented. I am able to get the response of 1 page but unable to get it for multiple pages I am unable to read that. Can you please see how I can get it the response

```
const panNumber = body.panNumber;
const fileName = files.filename;

fs.writeFileSync(filePath, files.content);
const bucket = msStorage.bucket(fileuploadBucket);
const [upload] = await bucket.upload(filePath, {
  destination: `${panNumber}/Invoices/${fileName}`,
  metadata: {
    cacheControl: 'public, max-age=315360000',
  },
  public: true,
});

const downloadLink = upload.metadata.mediaLink;
console.log(downloadLink);
// // console.log() // this is what you need

try {
  fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
} catch (unlinkError) {
  functions.logger.error(unlinkError);
  functions.logger.write({
    severity: 'ERROR',
    message: "Couldn't unlink file",
    filePath,
  });
}
const outputPrefix = `${body.source}`;

const fileRef = `gs://${fileuploadBucket}/${panNumber}/Invoices/${fileName}`;

const gcsDestinationUri = `gs://${fileuploadBucket}/${panNumber}/Invoices/${outputPrefix}/`;

const inputConfig = {
  mimeType: 'application/pdf',
  gcsSource: {
    uri: fileRef,
  },
};
const features = [{ type: 'DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION' }];

const outputConfig = {
  gcsDestination: {
    uri: gcsDestinationUri,
  },
};

const request = {
  requests: [
    {
      inputConfig: inputConfig,
      features: features,
      outputConfig: outputConfig,
      pages: [1, 2, -1],
    },
  ],
};

// Make the synchronous batch request.
const [result] = await client.asyncBatchAnnotateFiles(request);

const [filesResponse] = await result.promise();
console.log(filesResponse);
```